# Google Map API2 to API3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm busy moving my map from api2 to 3 and hitting a few bumps along the way. When using this code below I get a grey block and a map does not render. Console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined". I'm editing someone elses work so I'm not totally clued up on this, please let me know if you can spot something or if more details are needed.

```
// Initialise the required maps

Tour_Map = new Object();
Tour_Map.maps = new Array();

if (typeof (Tour_Map.GoogleMap) == 'undefined' || (!Tour_Map.GoogleMap instanceof Object)) {

Tour_Map.GoogleMap = function() {

    function Map (init, options) {

        // Check that we have the required information.
        if (init == null
                || typeof (init) != 'object'
                || typeof (init.map_container) == 'undefined') {
            alert('init failed');
            return false;
        }

        // Only proceed if the map container is visible     
        if ($('#' + init.map_container).is(":visible")) {

            // Set the default map options.
            var map_options = {
                'url': null,
                'zoom': 4,
                'lat': -3.5777508205127946,
                'lng': 28.1195068359375,
                'enableGoogleBar': 0,
                'googleBarOptions': {style: "new"},
                'directions': null,
                'markers': null,
                'route': null,
                'map': null
            }

            //Create map 
            var __map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById(init.map_container), {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(map_options.lat, map_options.lng),
                  zoom: map_options.zoom,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });


            // Return the Google Map
            this.__map = __map;

            return this;

        } // if map container is visible

        else {
            return null;
        }

    } // Map constructor end

    // Return our publically-accessible object.
    return ({Map: Map});

}();

}
$(window).load(function() {
// Create the Google Maps by looping through the maps array created earlier 
if (typeof (Tour_Map.maps) !== 'undefined') {
    for (var i in Tour_Map.maps) {
            Tour_Map.maps[i].map = new Tour_Map.GoogleMap.Map(Tour_Map.maps[i].init,           Tour_Map.maps[i].options);
    }
}
});
```

The loop through allows for multiple maps to be created and on the page with the map featured, there is this code:

```
DSA_Map.maps.push({
                    init : {
                        map_container: 'map_branches'
                    },
                    options: {
                        zoom : 5,
                        lat : -23.92175976307374, 
                        lng : 24.120724868774414,
                        directions: 1,
                        markers : [{exp:channel:entries orderby="title" sort="asc" channel="locations" dynamic="off" category="12|13|14" limit="5000" disable="{lv_disable_all}" {lv_tag_caching}}{exp:tied_entries this_entry_id="{entry_id}" tie="<branches" allow_php="yes" orderby="title" sort="asc"}<?php $locations[] = '<dd class="location">{title} <a class="expander">+</a></dd>'."\n";$locations[] = '<dd class="branch"><a href="#map_branches" id="marker_index'.$i++.'">{tied:title}</a></dd>'."\n"; ?>{embed="branch-finder/.js" entry_id="{tied:entry_id}" count="<?php echo $i;$i++; ?>"},{/exp:tied_entries}{/exp:channel:entries}]
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you add a plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you including the Google Maps Javascript API v3 before your code?

Comment: Seems like a slightly convoluted way of doing things.  At what point do you populate `Tour_Map.maps` so that this loop has something to iterate over? `for (var i in Tour_Map.maps) {`  The comment says `// Create the Google Maps by looping through the maps array created earlier ` and indeed it was: `Tour_Map.maps = new Array();` ... just nothing was inserted into that array from what I can see in your code